# No logro organizar la imagen ni céntrala en CSS

Tags: html, css, display

Hola es que hace rato estoy tratando de central una imagen en una pagina que estoy realizando y no logro centrarla de manera correcta, de antemano gracias al que me pueda ayudar. Estoy practicando lo que es todo de CSS ya que estoy terminando un curso que estoy realizando. lo que me esta costando es que la imagen quede centrada y que la navbar se ajuste también.

este es la pagina esta es la pagina que estoy diseñando.

(https://diegrox.github.io/Raccoon/)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Metal+Mania&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Francois+One&family=Odibee+Sans&family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    <title>Server Raccoon</title>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Barra de navegacion-->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">SERVIDORES Y PRECIOS</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">CUENTAS NETFLIX</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#">CONTACTENOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--Imagen Mapache-->
    <div class="container">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">          
    </div>
    <!--Titulo y Texto-->
   <div class="content">
        <head>
            <h1 class="title">SERVIDORES RACCOON</h1>
            <h3>NO TE QUEDES SIN JUGAR EN LINEA LOS JUEGOS QUE MAS TE GUSTAN, CON NUESTROS SERVIDORES PRIVADOS SIEMPRE ESTARAS ONLINE</h3>
        </head>
   </div> 
   <!--Footer-->
   <div>
     <footer>
         <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SERVERMAPACHE/">FACEBOOK</a>
         <a href="#">DISCORD</a>
     </footer>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
    html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(../img/fondo.jpg);
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: rgba(33, 199, 69, 0.9);
    border-radius: 15px;
}

nav ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #000;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
}

h1{
    font-size: 8em;
    font-family:'Metal Mania', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
    color: rgba(166, 30, 245, .8);
    text-shadow: 10px -10px 9px #000;
}

h3{
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgba(33, 199, 69, 0.9);
    text-shadow: 5px -5px 2px #000;
    border-radius: 35px;
}

footer{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

footer a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
    background: rgba(33, 199, 69, 0.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-shadow: 1px -1px 4px #000;
}

.container{
    display: inline-block;
}

.logo{
    width: 650px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
     h1{
        font-size: 4.5em;
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 760px){
 

}

@media screen and (min-width: 761px){
   
}
```

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Necesitamos agregues tu código aquí para reproducir tu escenario

Comment: Centrado vertical u horizontal o ambos?

Answer (score 0):

En general un elemento con `display:block` de anchura conocida se centra horizontalmente con `margin:auto`. En tu caso lo único que necesitas es quitarle el `display:flex` a tu `div.container` y ponerle el ancho de la imagen y un `margin:auto`.

Sea conocido o no el ancho (como en el caso de la barra de navegación), puedes centrar con flex, basta con que añadas `justify-content: center`.

```css
nav, div.container1 {
  display : flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.container2 {
  width : 100px;
  margin : auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <span>ITEM 1</span> |
  <span>ITEM 2</span> |
  <span>ITEM 3</span>
</nav>

<div class="container1">
  <img src="https://diegrox.github.io/Raccoon/img/logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Logo">
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <img src="https://diegrox.github.io/Raccoon/img/logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias fe funciono muy bien